# I'm trying to sort data corresponding to a list I made based on a csv in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv file with the columns: Name, Height, City
Now I need to return all the heights corresponding to similar cities.
So I have created a variable for all unique cities:

```
uniqueCity = []
for i in city:
    if i not in uniqueCity:
        uniqueCity.append(i)
```

I am able to print all heights corresponding to each city, but I cant seem to sort them on the height value per city

```
def printCity(city):
for i in uniqueCity:
    print(i)
    for j in range(len(city)):
        if i == city[j]:
            print(name[j], height[j])
```

What am I missing?

I am not allowed to use any third party libraries.

Full code:

```
import csv
with open('heightData.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(csvreader)


name = []
city = []
height = []
for row in csvreader:
    name.append(row[0])
    city.append(row[1])
    height.append(int(row[2]))


city.sort()

uniqueCity = []
for i in city:
    if i not in uniqueCity:
        uniqueCity.append(i)

def printCity(city):
    for i in uniqueCity:
        print(i)
        for j in range(len(city)):
            if i == city[j]:
                print(name[j], height[j])
printCity(city)
```

Sample data:

```
name,city,height
Mariam Cox,St_Paul,67
Daniel Ashley,St_Paul,65
Oliver Clay,Minneapolis,75
Rae Finley,Minneapolis,81
Brady Joyce,Virginia,68
Harding Jones,Virginia,80
```

Expected output:

```
Minneapolis:
Oliver Clay 75
Rae Finley 81
St_Paul:
Daniel Ashley 65
Mariam Cox 67
Virginia:
Brady Joyce 68
Harding Jones 80
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, once you separated the data into separate lists for each column, there's nothing connecting the same row for each column. Then, when you do `city.sort()`, the other columns don't also get sorted, and now you have the `city` column out of order with respect to the others.

Instead, you could put each row into a tuple, and add all tuples to a list. Then `sort()` that list using the `key` argument to select any column (in this case, select the `[2]` item of each row to sort by height:

```
with open('heightData.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(csvreader)
    csvdata = []
    for row in csvreader:
        row[2] = int(row[2])
        csvdata.append(tuple(row))

csvdata.sort(key=lambda row: row[2])
```

Which gives:

```
csvdata = [('Mariam Cox', 'St_Paul', 67),
 ('Brady Joyce', 'Virginia', 68),
 ('Oliver Clay', 'Minneapolis', 75),
 ('Harding Jones', 'Virginia', 80)]
```

---

From your edit, I see that you want to first *group* your data by city, and then print the names of people, sorted by their heights. You have two options to group your data:

1. Sort by city and then use python's builtin `itertools.groupby()`

```
import itertools

csvdata.sort(key=lambda row: row[1]) # Sort by city
grouped_rows = {k: list(v) for  k, v in itertools.groupby(csvdata, key=lambda row: row[1])} # Group by city
```

2. Create a dictionary where the keys are cities and the values are lists of  rows belonging to that city.

```
import collections

grouped_rows = collections.defaultdict(list)
for row in csvdata:
    city = row[1]
    grouped_rows[city].append(row)
```

Then, you can iterate over either of these `grouped_rows` objects, sort the lists within on the `[2]` item, and print them:

```
for city in sorted(grouped_rows.keys()):
    city_rows = sorted(grouped_rows[city], key=lambda row: row[2])
    print(city)
    for row in city_rows:
        print("\t", row[0], row[2])
```

```
Minneapolis
     Oliver Clay 75
St_Paul
     Mariam Cox 67
Virginia
     Brady Joyce 68
     Harding Jones 80
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But this isn't what i am looking for.
The output i have now is:

CITY A:
"All data linked to city A"
CITY B:
"All data linked to city B"
ETC

I just need the linked data, that's being returned to be sorted on the height value per city

Comment: @OussamaelBachiri please include expected output for your example input in your question

Comment: I have added it to the question, thanks for the heads up

Comment: @OussamaelBachiri Ah, I see. You want to first _group_ your data by city, and then print the names of people sorted by their heights. Take a look at my edited answer

Comment: Thanks for your responses and time! I wasn't able to get your solution working for myself, because of my inexperience. But importing collections and the tuple tip did put me on the right track! I posted the snippet that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For the assignment, it had to be a function. But this seems to work for me.

```
#create tuple of all heights corresponding to each city
def heightTuple(city):
    cityHeight = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(len(city)):
        cityHeight[city[i]].append(height[i])
    for i in cityHeight:
        cityHeight[i].sort()
    print(cityHeight)
```